# How to get data From two different Branch in Flutter Firestore or Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

Since I was a Java Developer Before it was very straightforward to fetch data from any branches we want and then show it in a ListView but now m facing this issue and don't know how can I get data from different streams and make a List of it in its Model

The Data Structure is
[image: FireStore Database]

[image: FireStore Database]

[image: Realtime Database]

I have tried 2 methods but it's not java so it's not working as I want it to do

First Trial

```
List<VideoModel> videoModel = [];
  bool loading = true;

  firebaseWork() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').get().then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        var uidFromDB = element.id;
        Map userDetailsMap = element.data();
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Users')
            .doc(uidFromDB)
            .collection('Uploads')
            .get()
            .then(
              (value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
                Map videoDetailMap = element.data();
                videoModel.add(VideoModel(
                  userName: userDetailsMap['name'],
                  videoTitle: videoDetailMap['videoTitle'],
                  videoLocation: videoDetailMap['videoLocation'],
                  userPhoto: userDetailsMap['photoUrl'],
                ));
              }),
            );
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    await firebaseWork();
    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    });
  }
```

and Then I saw a related post which I have tried but not sure why it escapes the code

```
class _HomeScreenBodyWidgetState extends State<HomeScreenBodyWidget> {
  List<VideoModel> videoModel = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').get(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            var uidFromDB;
            Map userDetailsMap;
            snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((element) {
              uidFromDB = element.id;
              userDetailsMap = element.data() as Map;
            });
            return Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('Users')
                      .doc(uidFromDB)
                      .collection('Uploads')
                      .get(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snap) {
                    if (!snap.hasData) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    } else {

                      snap.data!.docs.forEach((element) async {
                        // print(element.data());
                        Map videoDetailMap = element.data() as Map;
                        videoModel.add(VideoModel(
                          userName: userDetailsMap['name'],
                          videoTitle: videoDetailMap['videoTitle'],
                          videoLocation: videoDetailMap['videoLocation'],
                          userPhoto: userDetailsMap['photoUrl'],
                        ));
                      });
                      print(videoModel[0].videoLocation);
                      
                      // todo return ListView From Here
                      return Center(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Text('No Posts in Future to View'),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }),
            );

          }
        });
  }

  Widget homeWidget(BuildContext context) => Expanded(
        child: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600
            ? Container(
                width: 600,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: videoModel.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                    return PostLayoutWidget();
                  },
                ),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: videoModel.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                  return PostLayoutWidget();
                },
              ),
      );
}
```

Comment: You mention that "it is not working as I want it". Can you please clarify what it does? Also, to save on your read bandwidth, take a look at [Collection Group Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). FlutterFire has an implementation: [collectionGroup method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html)

Comment: I want to fetch the data first and as the data fetching finishes I want then the widget to change from circular progress to Listview builder but it changes before the data fetches thus it shows that the length of data is 0